# fill javascript array from template engine

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, smarty

i want to fill javascript array with raintpl like below code.problem in this line is `,` end of line. for example this line :

```
var theSummaries = new Array({loop="lastNewsTicker"}"{$value.subject}",{/loop});
```

after rendering in firefox create this result:

```
var theSummaries = new Array("Hello","How","Are",);
```

comma in after `"Are"` is my problem and that create error in define javascript array.

how to fill this array and resolv problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var theSummaries = new Array(
     {loop="lastNewsTicker"}
         "{$value.subject}"
         {if !$smarty.section.value.last}, {/if}
     {/loop}
     );
```